# ¿Cómo crear un directorio con nombre "con" usando C#?

Tags: c#, windows

Estoy intentando crear un directorio con nombre `con` directamente en la unidad C de mi disco local con el siguiente segmento de código:

```
if (!Directory.Exists("c:\\con"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\con");
```

Pero me envía el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\'.

Pero, si intento crear el directorio `temp` no me envía ningún error:

```
if (!Directory.Exists("c:\\temp"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\temp");
```

¿Por qué al intentar crear un directorio con el nombre `con` me envía error? ¿Es posible crearlo por medio de C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En Windows, el nombre `con` es un nombre reservado, por ende no es posible crear carpetas ni archivos con dicho nombre.

Esto es herencia de MS-DOS, en donde ciertos nombres eran reservados para los controladores de dispositivos. Esta limitación se ha mantenido en todas las versiones de windows.

La lista completa es la siguiente:

```
 Nombre    Función
 ------    --------
 A:-Z:     Letras de unidades
 AUX       Dispositivo auxiliar, usualmente un puerto serial
 CLOCK$    Reloj de tiempo real del sistema
 COM1      Puerto serial 1
 COM2      Puerto serial 2
 COM3      Puerto serial 3
 COM4      Puerto serial 4
 CON       Teclado y pantalla
 LPT1      Puerto paralelo de impresora 1
 LPT2      Puerto paralelo de impresora 2
 LPT3      Puerto paralelo de impresora 3
 NUL       Dispositivo nulo
 PRN       Dispositivo en la lista de sistema, usualmente un puerto paralelo
```

Fuente: [Soporte de Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/74496/ms-dos-device-driver-names-cannot-be-used-as-file-names)